# How to develop locally with service worker?

Tags: reactjs

Instead of generating a build every time I make a change, I want to use the service worker while developing. I've already managed to use the https protocol with a valid certificate, but the service worker doesn't install it. I imagine it is related to the following error "No matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the current page also controls the start of the URL from the manifest."

[image]